# How to configure mysqldump to avoid max_allowed_packet error

Tags: mysql

Honestly it baffles me that with a completely default installation of mysql if I run `mysqldump` with default parameters it generates a SQL file that can't be imported into another completely default installation of mysql.  From what I can gather it's got something to do with the `max_allowed_packet` setting and/or the `net_buffer_length` setting.  I've read a bunch about this, and tried tweaking it a bunch of ways on both the export and import sides, but it still doesn't work.  I keep getting the packet too big error on import.  From everything I've read, here's my best guess:

```
mysqldump --net_buffer_length=50000 myschema > giant_file.sql
```

Because I read [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9753) that `mysqldump` refers to `max_allowed_packet` as `net_buffer_length` because ... uhh ... anyway.  Then to import

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=999999 myschema < giant_file.sql
```

But this still doesn't work.  How do I export / import the database???

Comment: 999999 ~ 1M? How did you tweak `max_allowed_packet`, in `/etc/my.cnf`, under [mysqldump] section? Are you importing on the same host? What exactly error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to make the supreme sacrifice for mysqldumps: bypass extended INSERTs.

This makes each row happen in its own INSERT.

It also increase the size of the mysqldump output.

```
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert --net_buffer_length=50000 myschema > gigantic_file.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: i still get packet bigger than max_allowed_packet bytes even after bypassing extended inserts ? Could there be any other factors deciding this ?